# Limitations of returning an interface in a Spring @Bean method

Tags: java, spring

I came across these paragraphs while reading the Spring docs for @Bean methods:

> You can also declare your @Bean method with an interface (or base class) return type, as the
>   following example shows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

> However, this limits the visibility for advance type prediction to the specified interface type
>   (TransferService). Then, with the full type (TransferServiceImpl) known to the container only once,
>   the affected singleton bean has been instantiated. Non-lazy singleton beans get instantiated
>   according to their declaration order, so you may see different type matching results depending on
>   when another component tries to match by a non-declared type (such as @Autowired
>   TransferServiceImpl, which resolves only once the transferService bean has been instantiated).

Then in the follwoing paragraph it mentions:

> If you consistently refer to your types by a declared service interface, your @Bean
>   return types may safely join that design decision. However, for components that
>   implement several interfaces or for components potentially referred to by their
>   implementation type, it is safer to declare the most specific return type possible (at
>   least as specific as required by the injection points that refer to your bean).

Can someone explain the meaning of the prvious paragraphs? I know that it's a good practice to program for interfaces. However, it seems there is a kind of limitation when used with @Bean methods.

Comment: Must your code need to know the object is a TransferServiceImpl or is it enough to know it is a TransferService?

Comment: I just want to understand this paragraph, regardless of any use case.

Comment: That is what the paragraph means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your bean like you listed:

```
    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
```

Then resolving the following bean will always work:

```
@Autowired
TransferService transferService;
```

But trying to Autowire the concrete class will NOT ALWAYS work, because Spring doesn't know it yet at the start. It only knows how to inject the Implementation after the singleton bean has been instantiated (aka, some other class has @Autowired the interface).

```
@Autowired 
TransferServiceImpl transferService;
```

ps: Don't use field injection, but use the constructor. Showing Field injection here to keep it concise.

Comment: "Spring doesn't know it yet at the start. It only knows how to inject the Implementation after the singleton bean has been instantiated". Shouldn't all objects returned by @Bean methods by registered in the container at start up, regardless they were autowired or not?

Comment: Spring only know about the types 'returned' by @Bean method signature. Since your method signature returns an Interface, it only knows the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: @TomCools a newbie question: for bean methods, is it generally a good idea to always return the interface type or the concrete implementation type?